# How do i force load/ reload the winform in my program

Tags: c#, winforms

I have searched a bit on the internet and found solutions involving reloading the winforms with `Application.DoEvents()`and 
`Control.Invalidate() Control.Update()`

But none of it works. I am trying to make program which takes a screenshot and then moves the pixels around randomly to the right. Kind of like a screen melter.

The only problem is that the form only shows when the application is done moving the pixels. How can i force him to show and re-draw whilst he is doing that.

This is the painting method:

```
// Draw the screenshot...
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(@".\screenshot.jpg");

    int Xcount;

    int maxXValue = 1919;
    int maxYValue = 1079;

    Random random = new Random();
    for (Xcount = 0; Xcount < maxXValue; Xcount++)
    {
        screenshot.Invalidate();
        screenshot.Image = myBitmap;
        screenshot.Update();

        for (int Ycount = 0; Ycount < maxYValue; Ycount++)
        {
            int calculatedX = Xcount + random.Next(0, maxXValue);
            if (calculatedX > maxXValue) calculatedX = maxXValue;

            myBitmap.SetPixel(Xcount, Ycount, myBitmap.GetPixel(calculatedX, Ycount));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `screenshot`?

Comment: `private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox screenshot;`

Comment: Why are you setting the PictureBox's image inside the for loop?

Comment: I thought this was necessary to update the image everytime it drew a new line of pixels in the form.

Comment: Well, your code looks basically working for me... But I can't get your point - are you sure you want to call all of this code certainly from `Form_Paint`? Note that `Form_Paint` called every time form needs to be redrawn. For example, when hidden/shown again, hovered by another window and so on...

Comment: So i should not run the for loop in this method ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it refreshes just fine. My guess is that your image location in your Bitmap constructor is incorrect? Test it with a direct path:
`new Bitmap(@"c:\yourImgDir\screenshot.jpg");` and see if that works?

Comment: He does use the right screenshot though. The only problem is that the form only shows when the for loop is completed. My teacher just gave me advice to try and move my code around over the Load,Paint and Shown methods.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using Form1_Load and Form1_Shown, Thanks @Andy Korneyev
This is my code now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScreenOutput
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    private Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(@".\screenshot.jpg");
    private PictureBox screenshot;
    private int Xcount;
    private int maxXValue = 1919;
    private int maxYValue = 1079;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        screenshot.Load(@".\screenshot.jpg");
        screenshot.Image = myBitmap;
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (Xcount = 0; Xcount < maxXValue; Xcount++)
        {
            screenshot.Invalidate();
            screenshot.Update();

            for (int Ycount = 0; Ycount < maxYValue; Ycount++)
            {
                int calculatedX = Xcount + random.Next(0, maxXValue);
                if (calculatedX > maxXValue) calculatedX = maxXValue;
                myBitmap.SetPixel(Xcount, Ycount, myBitmap.GetPixel(calculatedX, Ycount));

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```